# How to convert Generic List<string> to string?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to find Top 3 values in the list which is coming from ms-sql and this is the Json Format, there is add only one object in the list using **FirstOrDefault()** but I want to add all objects in list, whenever I tried to remove FirstOrDefault then Its Give me
**Error:**
Cannot convert Generic List to string

```
public void getTopProducts()
{
    var getProd = (from orders in _Db.tbl_orders
                  select orders.order_details).ToList();

    
    var Products = getProd;

    if (Products != null)
    {
                                                          //the error occur here
        List<Cart> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cart>>(Products);

       var itemMax =  products.Max(x => x.prod_qty);

        Console.WriteLine(itemMax);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why you need to deserialize from a `List<T>` instance to `List<Cart>`? Don't see any reason that you need the deserialization here.

Comment: @YongShun because it is the array of objects which is coming from database

Comment: How does `order_details` look like?

Comment: @shingo its array of objects format

Comment: Can you show some examples?

Comment: @shingo Look Like this  [{"prod_id":6007,"prod_name":"T-Shirt For Gym","prod_qty":1,"prod_price":450,"prod_total":450,"prod_image":"blue-T-shi231711875.png"},{"prod_id":6013,"prod_name":"Blazer","prod_qty":1,"prod_price":1000,"prod_total":1000,"prod_image":"blazer233324860.png"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from `List<string>` to `List<List<Cart>>`

```
var cartLists = Products.Select(details => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cart>>(details));
```

If you want to continue to flatten `List<List<Cart>>` to `List<Cart>`

```
var carts = cartLists.SelectMany(cartList => cartList);
```

Comment: Thanks Its Working But How to get the maximum quantity from all the products ? from list

Comment: `carts.Max(x => x.prod_qty);`